# Regarding locks in Sybase ASE Database

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I am using Sybase ASE DB system.
On one fine day I observed a deadlock on one table.
here, process1 was trying to write to the table, and the other process2 received a notification from process1, and the process2 did ran select query on the table.
This resulted deadlock. and I can clearly see it from Sybase Logs.

Current lock scheme is 'allpages'
So, I did google about this, and the solution I found is to change the lock scheme from 'allpages' to 'datapage'

My question here is, rather I don't understand, when lock scheme changed from allpages to datapage, do index page and data page update occur within a single operation (i.e. atomic operation)?

As per SAP ASE portal:

**The updates to the index pages are performed using latches, which are non transactional. Latches are held only as long as required to perform the physical changes to the page and are then released immediately. *Index page entries are implicitly locked by locking the data page*. No transactional locks are held on index pages**

I just want to understand, whether the update to index page and data page are atomic or not?